# body onload except for a specific image?

Tags: javascript, html, onload

I have a HTML page that includes lots of text and images. One specific image is slow to load. I want to do something when all the rest of the page is loaded, except for that specific image. Something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body onloadExceptSlowImage="doSomething();">
    ... several things, including some quick images ...
    <img id="SlowImage" src="slowImage.jpg" />
    ... several things, including some quick images ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 1):

After giving it some thought I came out with a simple workaround:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function doSomething() {
        // Do whatever
        document.getElementById("SlowImage").src="slowImage.jpg";
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="doSomething();">
    ... several things, including some quick images ...
    <img id="SlowImage" src="tempImage.jpg" />
    ... several things, including some quick images ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you must change onloadExceptSlowImage with onload then remove src attribute from img tag.

Comment: Yes already edited (it was a typo - I simply copied from the original post). Why should I remove the src attribute from the img tag?

Comment: When you remove src attribute, at the first time your img element load without any image. So you can do something after load page and at the end set src attribute to load image.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
let loadedImagesEvent = new Event("loadExceptSlowImage")
let loadedImages = []
let lengthOfAllImages = document.querySelectorAll("img").length
let imagesExceptSlowImage = document.querySelectorAll("img:not(#SlowImage)")

imagesExceptSlowImage.forEach((img) => {
   img.onload = () => {
      loadedImages.push(img)
      if (loadedImages.length == lengthOfAllImages - 1) {
         window.dispatchEvent(loadedImagesEvent)
      }
   }
})

window.addEventListener("loadExceptSlowImage", () => {
   // Your Code
})
```

Comment: @FreeBud Yeah. But because images are loaded after text it should work fine